# Is the Internet only a buffering nightmare for me?

Tags: vpn, internet, connection, privacy, buffer

So here's the thing. I have a fast fiber connection since many years. It is fast. However, it can never be used directly for privacy reasons, so I have to use a VPN service (paid for with Bitcoin and registered with a dedicated e-mail address).

It isn't the case *all* the time, but numerous times a day, I find myself utterly unable to stream video (YouTube, Twitch) or even Internet radio. I get to watch and listen for two seconds, then it freezes and starts buffering for 15 seconds, then I get another two seconds, etc.

All stories about how we used to have "only 300 baud back in the day" aside, this is absolutely *torturous*. Especially knowing that it could be super fast if I were using the actual connection directly, and that I'm paying *extra* for this "experience"...

It never seems to matter if I disconnect/reconnect, change servers, change proxies, etc. Sometimes it works, but often it's unwatchable. And this causes a lot of frustration and anger.

Also, I don't play video games in general, but once a week, I do play a session of a very obscure and old real-time action game (but the client is modern, so it's not old network code), and my ping is ridiculous when going through the VPN.

Even loading webpages can be very sketchy and sluggish.

It's possible that it has got worse after this "Wuhan virus" thing, but it was basically the same prior to it as well, so I wouldn't attribute it to "general congestion".

Since it's just not an option to skip the VPN, for privacy reasons, is there anything I can do other than sending e-mails to the thugs running the VPN service?

I did spend forever searching for an alternative, but there basically seems to be nothing out there. All the major VPNs seem *entirely* compromised and don't provide (or seem to provide) a bunch of HTTP/SOCKS proxies, which is a requirement for me. (I cannot pay for two separate ones.)

Given how I'm constantly harassed by websites and perpetual "reCAPTCHA"s, it seems like this current VPN provides *some* minimal amount of privacy...

Comment: Try a free VPN. And I absolutely disagree that all VPNs are compromised.

Comment: The internet is only a buffering nightmare if you insist on using a VPN to access it. Many services actively disrupt known VPN sources. Your "perpetual reCAPTCHAs" are a part of that.

Answer (score 1):

Find a cloud provider with conditions and prices you like, and deploy your own private VPN, only for you. Tune it for your purposes (provide SOCKS proxies, eleminate buffer bloat, ...). Guaranteed to not be compromised, because you control everything.

**Edit**

If you mean by privacy "I can do criminal things but won't get caught", then yes, this solution is not for you. If you mean by privacy "the sites I visit won't know who I am", then this works perfectly fine with this solution - the sites you'll visit will only see the IP address of the cloud provider.

Yes, the cloud provider knows who you are. So does your ISP and the VPN you use, if they talk to each other.